# Controlling access to Spring Security OAuth2 endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to control what clients can generate access tokens in [Spring Security OAuth2.0](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).
I'd like to allow only one client to be able to generate access tokens (access `/oauth/authorize`, `/oauth/token`) and all the other ones to validate them.
The documentation says that I should use the standard Spring Security `WebSecurityConfigurer` to achieve such an access granularity. However, all the configuration I do does not affect access to the end-points.

I tried the following configuration to allow only client `mgmt` to generate tokens:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
        .inMemory()
          .withClient("mgmt")
          .secret("pass")
          .authorities("ROLE_WRITE")
          .and()

          .withClient("resource")
          .secret("pass")
          .authorities("ROLE_READ");
  }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class EndpointAuthorizationConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/token")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token")
        .hasAuthority("ROLE_WRITE")
        .and()
        .httpBasic();
  }
}
```

I also tried to define users one more time in the `EndpointAuthorizationConfig` class, but that did not help. Client `resource` still can access those endpoints.

```java
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("mgmt")
        .password("pass")
        .roles("WRITE");
}
```

Comment: I too have have this issue. I have created a ticket here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/496